# SKPhysicsJointPin lowerAngleLimit and upperAngleLimit values

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit

I have set shouldEnableLimits on a SKPhysicsJointPin but I cannot figure out what the values of lowerAngleLimit and upperAngleLimit should be.

For example I want to set the limits to +- 20 degrees. What is the formula to set these values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sprite Kit uses radians as its unit of angle measurement. 20 degrees = 0.35 radians, therefore, to set the limits to +- 20 degrees off the original rotation:

```
pinJoint.shouldEnableLimits = YES;
pinJoint.lowerAngleLimit = -0.35;
pinJoint.upperAngleLimit = 0.35;
```

Also, remember that lower limit <= upper limit, otherwise you'll get an assertion failure.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that setting lowerAngleLimit to any negative value causes SpriteKit to freak out, so this won't work.  Appears to be a bug in SpriteKit.